# How can I use a range inside numpy.fromfunction?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a matrix whose value at index (i,j) will be `f(i,j),` for a function that I'm defining.  I'm trying to do this with `numpy.fromfunction` and I haven't been able to get it to work.  Here's the code

```
import numpy as np

def f(i,j):
    return sum((i+1)//k for k in np.arange(1,j+2))

def M(N):
    shape = np.array([N,N])
    np.fromfunction(f, shape,dtype = np.int)

A= M(5)
```

I get the error

> builtins.TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

in the call to `fromfunction` and I suppose it must have to do with `np.arange`.

Originally, I had `range(1,j+2)` but then I got the error

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Can you tell me what I need to do, please?

Comment: `shape` should be a [tuple of ints](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html). Try `(N, N)` instead of `np.array([N, N])`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That's what I had originally, and I got a syntax error.  Changing to np.array([N,N]) fixed it.  That's not where the error is coming from.

Comment: Okay, it was just a guess.

Comment: I think fromfunction passes whole arrays to your function, not scalars.  Test it with a function that displays its inputs.

Comment: @hpaulj have you been reading my thoughts again ? ;-)

Comment: To still add something useful to this question: you need to `return` the result of `M` ;)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, of course.  I guess the code never made it that far before, so I didn't notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to `vectorize` `f` first:

```
>>> np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (5, 5), dtype=int)
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 4,  6,  7,  8,  8],
       [ 5,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Indeed, `fromfunction` passes the coordinates not one-by-one but in one go:

```
>>> def f(i, j):
...     print(i, j)
...     return sum((i+1)//k for k in range(1, j+2))
... 
>>> np.fromfunction(f, (5, 5), dtype=int)
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]] [[0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paul/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1914, in fromfunction
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: On the money.  Thanks.  I don't think I would ever have figured that out.  I've just reread the numpy documentation on `fromfunction` and I see that I interpreted the description, "Construct an array by executing a function over each coordinate" wrong.   (Of course, if I had understood it correctly, since I didn't know about `vectorize`, I would have computed each element separately and stuffed it in the array, without asking on SO for a better way.)

Comment: @saulspatz Don't beat yourself up; the docs are a bit misleading I'd say.