# How can I use numpy create list out of another list with modified elements

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, list-comprehension

I am not new at all to Python programming, but I am completely new to the Numpy module. I need to use this module for it's very fast and efficient.

Say I have an array called `noise` which is defined as follows:

```
noise = [[uniform(0, 1) for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
```

In numpy terms, it is defined, I believe, as so:

```
noise = np.uniform(0, 1, (size, size))
```

Now say I want to generate a new array which takes the noise array and replaces every element `noise[i][j]` of its elements by the function `function(i, j)`
Using python's built-in list comprehension, I would simply say:

```
modified_noise = [[function(i, j) for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
```

My question, is: how can I do that using the numpy module.

Comment: What's wrong with using the list comprehension?  Looks like `function` only works with scalar inputs, right?  There's no way of getting around evaluating it once for each of the `size*size` (i,j) pairs, is there?

Comment: I don't see how `modified_noise` is related to `noise`.  `function` only takes coordinates as arguments, not `noise`.

Comment: By the way, there's no `np.uniform`.. `noise = np.random.random_sample((size, size))` is the right expression.  You also seem to be confused about the concept of 'replacing every element'.

Comment: Oh yes, there is a `numpy.uniform`. I used it and it actually works just as expected.

Comment: Also, `modified_noise` is to be constructed from `noise`. The two are related but only inside the definition of the function `function` which in my case is a turbulance function (I called it function to give you a more abstract version of the code)

Comment: It's time to ask for a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) for this:

```
modified_noise = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: function(i, j), (size, size), dtype=float)
```

This constructs an array by executing a function over each coordinate.

Related: [How can I use a range inside numpy.fromfunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059667/how-can-i-use-a-range-inside-numpy-fromfunction)

Comment: On use of `fromfunction`: [How can I use a range inside numpy.fromfunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059667/how-can-i-use-a-range-inside-numpy-fromfunction)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a numpy array directly from a list of lists like:

#### Code:

```
np.array(modified_noise)
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [[i * j for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
print(data)

import numpy as np
print(np.array(data))
```

#### Results:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]]

[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 0  2  4  6  8]
 [ 0  3  6  9 12]
 [ 0  4  8 12 16]]
```